# How to get changed_fields in Django REST Framework Serializers during update?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there any way that I can get the `'changed_fields'` before updating the model using `ModelSerializer`?

I want functionality like:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      fields = '__all__'
      model = MyModel

  def update(self, validated_data):
      // Access old values and new values of model so that I can compare them.
      super(MySerializer, self).update(validated_data)
```

I don't want to query the database to fetch the `old_values`, because we've over millions of rows and it will take time to fetch that.

Comment: Doesn't `update` have a parameter `instance`? `def update(self, instance, validated_data):`

Comment: @IainShelvington, I'm trying to maintain the history on database level. the Serializer method will do it in Application Level. Any suggestions?

Comment: This package can be used to track changes to any instances of a model https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **`update()`** method takes two parameters **`instance`** and **`validated_data`**. The **`instance`** is the ***model instance*** that going to be **updated** and the **`validated_data`** is a `dict` that contain the data to be updated

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = MyModel

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            new_value = value
            old_value = getattr(instance, field)

        return super(MySerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

based on Arakkal answer, however need to handle nested relations:

```
def changed_fields(instance, validated_data, changed_data=[]):
    for field, value in validated_data.items():
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            if value != getattr(instance, field, None):
                changed_data.append(field)
        else:
            changed_fields(getattr(instance, field), validated_data[field], changed_data)
    return changed_data
```